# Is it possible to use a folder named vimfiles to replace .vim in macvim?

Tags: vim, editor, macvim, setting

I am using MacVim at home and using gvim in Windows at work. Since I use git to sync my vim settings, I want the settings to be in the same folder named vimfiles. I set runtimepath in my .gvimrc like this:

```
set runtimepath=~/vimfiles/,$VIMRUNTIME
```

but the plugins in `~/vimfiles/plugin` seems not been loaded by MacVim. Am I doing something wrong with it?

Is it because the subfolders in vimfiles were not recursively added to runtimepath?

Answer (score 11):

I'm not sure why you are worried about forcing Vim on MacOS to understand Window's file-naming convention, when Vim can do the right thing and use the standard '`.`' naming on Windows too. You're going against the flow.

This is from [the Vim wiki](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Synchronize_configuration_to_many_computers):

> One helpful Vim setting in a mixed-OS environment is to use .vim for Vim user settings also for Windows systems (Vim automatically picks up a .vimrc config file instead of _vimrc by default). The following snippet in .vimrc will do the trick, and thus allow you to synchronize without directory renaming:
>
> " On Windows, also use '.vim' instead of 'vimfiles'; this makes synchronization
>   " across (heterogeneous) systems easier.

```
if has('win32') || has('win64')
  set runtimepath=$HOME/.vim,$VIM/vimfiles,$VIMRUNTIME,$VIM/vimfiles/after,$HOME/.vim/after
endif
```

That's what I did on my WinXP machine at work, and I synchronize between my Mac, XP and about five Linux hosts by copying a tarball across.

Comment: Thanks for your answer,very useful information,I will try it on my winXP machine.

Answer (score 6):

Just make `~/.vim` a symbolic link to your `~/vimfiles` directory and it should work beautifully.

Comment: thanks very much,you solved my problem.But I still want to know why set runtimepath doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

According to the `:h initialization`, loading plugin scripts (search for `^4\.`) is done before GUI-specific initializations are performed (search for `^8\.`), so you should place this line into `~/.vimrc`, not into `~/.gvimrc`.

Comment: thanks for your answer,I tried to rename .gvimrc to .vimrc just now,still not work,I even tried to set it like this in .vimrc:"set runtimepath=~/vimfiles/,~/vimfiles/plugin,$VIMRUNTIME",with no luck,very strange.

Comment: @treblam You should not add `~/vimfiles/plugin` to rtp. What do `:scriptnames` show? Maybe for some reason (like a shell alias that adds `-u NONE`) vimrc is not loaded at all? Does explicit loading of plugins (`runtime! plugin/**/*.vim`) in the current session work?

Comment: It is my fault,the snipmate plugin has a problem which make me think all the plugins are still not been loaded,the result of `:scriptnames` shows they are loaded now,thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `set runtimepath+=/path/to/vimfiles` (note the `+=`)? Also it's possible that you need to do that for all the subfolders.

Since you are using Git, you may set the working directory to `~/.vim` on the Mac and whatever it is on the Windows machine making the name of the folder irrelevant.

```
$ git config worktree /Users/username/.vim
```

I use DropBox to sync my `~/.vim` folders on all my machines (Mac@work, Mac@home, Ubuntu@home and a Linode VPS somewhere). All the `autoload`, `bundle`, etc. folders are in a `DOTFILES/vim` subfolder of my DropBox and symlinked to `~/.vim/autoload`, `~/.vim/bundle`, `~/.vim/syntax`, etc.

Simply symlinking `~/Dropbox/DOTFILES/vim` to `~/.vim` would work, too, but I wanted to keep the ability to have things specific to a machine stay on this machine. Views, for example.

My `.vimrc` contains only these few lines:

```
source ~/Dropbox/DOTFILES/vimrc

" Quickly edit/reload the vimrc file
nmap <silent> <leader>ev :tabnew ~/Dropbox/DOTFILES/vimrc<CR>
nmap <silent> <leader>sv :so ~/Dropbox/DOTFILES/vimrc<CR>
```

Setting it up on a new machine would take 2 or 3 minutes max, I guess, and keeping the whole thing up to date is totally effortless.